# Replace Values in One Column with 12 Different Categories in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

I want to use "if_else" statement to replace the values in "PROPERTY_USE_DESC" with new categories of "residential", "business", "restaurant", "art", "education", "stores", "other" and five other categories.

For example, if the values in "PROPERTY_USE_DESC" are "429 - Multifamily dwelling", I will replace it with "residential". Because I want to replace values in 13000+ rows with 12 new values, I choose to use "if_else" statement.

The statement structure I am using is :

```
highest$PROPERTY_USE_DESC_2 <- 
if_else(
highest$PROPERTY_USE_DESC %in%
c("419 - 1 or 2 family dwelling",
"429 - Multifamily dwelling",
"400 - Residential, other",
"439 - Boarding/rooming house, residential hotels",
"449 - Hotel/motel, commercial",
"459 - Residential board and care",
"460 - Dormitory-type residence, other", 
true = "Residential", 
false = if_else(
highest$PROPERTY_USE_DESC %in% c("361 - Jail, prison (not juvenile)",
"363 - Reformatory, juvenile detention center",
"365 - Police station"), 
true = "Public Safety", 
false = if_else (condition, true, false)))
```

The warning I got is:

`Error in if_else(highest$PROPERTY_USE_DESC %in% c("419 - 1 or 2 family dwelling",  :  could not find function "if_else"`

Can yall help me out out here with this statement please? Thank you so much!

I have searched numerous articles on replacing values in column and if_else statement. The method I used corresponding the "could not find 'if_else'" is to make sure the argument is complete and logical. I changed the condition using `"is.na", "list c()", and "for i in 1:nrow"`, none of those changes worked.

I also made sure the targeted datatable and the column are specified.

I am wondering if r does not know what data table and column I am referring to, since some of the methods I looked up include creating a new dataframe, or using:

```
highest %in% lazy_dt() %in% select(PROPERTY_USE_DESC) %in% mutate(PROPERTY_USE_DESC_2 = if_else(PROPERTY_USE_DESC %in%  :
```

Also, I understand that if_else statement is trickier and can always get flagged with error. Please help thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you load the `dplyr` library ?

Comment: I have, I also chenged my code to: highest <- highest %>% mutate (PROPERTY_USE_DESC = ifelse (PROPERTY_USE_DESC == c('419 - 1 or 2 family dwelling',
                                   '429 - Multifamily dwelling'),
                              "Residential", ifelse (condition, true, false).        but it did not return the value "reasidential", rather returned N/A.

Comment: Are there overlapping ranges? For example that each category you want is within a range of 361-365, 419-460, etc you can consider grabbing the number and then use simply a cut assign it Residential and Public Safety

Comment: I just checked there's no overlapping ranges. I'm guessing if it's because my values are characters (should be converted to factors?) and the if_else statement returns "N/A" in the rows that are supposed to be "residential".

Answer (score 0):

As OP mentions in the comments that there are no overlapping ranges you could use cut like this.

```
df$PROPERTY_USE_DESC2 <- cut(
  as.numeric(gsub("(^\\d+).+", "\\1", df$PROPERTY_USE_DESC)), 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 360, 365, 399, 460, Inf), 
  labels = c("other", "Public Safety", "other", "Residential", "other")
)
```

**note** as I do not know all ranges I made the example with alternating "others", to catch any ranges outside of those defined.

**results**

```
                                  PROPERTY_USE_DESC PROPERTY_USE_DESC2
1                      419 - 1 or 2 family dwelling        Residential
2                        429 - Multifamily dwelling        Residential
3                          400 - Residential, other        Residential
4  439 - Boarding/rooming house, residential hotels        Residential
5                     449 - Hotel/motel, commercial        Residential
6                  459 - Residential board and care        Residential
7             460 - Dormitory-type residence, other        Residential
8                 361 - Jail, prison (not juvenile)      Public Safety
9      363 - Reformatory, juvenile detention center      Public Safety
10                             365 - Police station      Public Safety
```